# How to delete all characters in one line after "]" with sed?

Tags: linux, sed, awk

How to delete all characters in one line after "]" with sed ?

Im trying to grep some file using cat, awk. Now my oneliner returns me something like

`121.122.121.111] other characters in logs from sendmail.... :)`

Now I want to delete all after "]" character (with "]"). I want only `121.122.121.111` in my output.

I was googling for that particular example of sed but didn't find any help in those examples.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
 echo "121.122.121.111] other characters in logs from sendmail...." | sed 's/].*//'
```

So if you have a file full of lines like that you can do

```
 sed 's/].*//' filename
```

Answer (score 14):

How about `cut` instead:

```
cat logfile | cut -d "]" -f1
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
sed 's|\(.*\)\] .*$|\1|'
```

should do what you want. The `\(.*\)]` will capture all the text up to the `]` into a remembered pattern and then the `\1` substitutes it for the whole line.